# Remote directory expression string

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-el

In my project i use Spring Integration Sftp. I tried configure `remoteDirectoryExpression` with spEL, but the main problem, that SFTP folder value i store in application properties as `sftp.folder=/test/`.

```
handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString("\'" + properties.getFolder() + "\'" + ".concat(headers['region'])");
```

`properties.getFolder()` is a class with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

This solution works fine, but i do not like it. So, it is possible somehow to write spEl expression without my curly braces?

Comment: What do you mean with `my curly braces` ? What is really wrong with such a strong typed solution?

Comment: @ArtemBilan , actually all is ok, but i do not like this  `"\'" + properties.getFolder() + "\'"`. Wanted to do it with single spEl expression, but can`t get property from application.properties using expressions like ${}

Comment: You don't need to escape single quotes within double quotes. `"'" + properties.getFolder() + "'" + ".concat(headers['region'])");`. You can also put the single quotes in the property value and then `properties.getQuotedFolder() + ".concat(headers['region'])");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but can`t get property from application.properties using expressions like ${}

That's right: you can't do that on this setter level because there is no properties placeholder knowledge because it is already a plain Java call.

You can do what you want via a `@Value` annotation on the property of the `@Configuration` class on or via `@Bean` method parameter:

```
@Bean
FtpMessageHandler ftpMessageHandler(@Value("'${sftp.folder}' + headers['region']") String remoteDirectory)
```